# In Postgres / SQL how can I search for names that doesn't start with a letter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find all the names that start with numbers, weird chars (.,-#$, etc) and everything else that isn't a letter.

For example, i have 3 names: John, #1 John and 2John. What I want to get is the last 2 names. (and I don't know what weird chars the names can start, so it must be something like ![a-Z])..

I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   name ~ '^[^a-zA-Z]'
```

If accented or non-Latin characters don't fall under your definition of "weird stuff", you may use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   name ~ '^[^[:alpha:]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

[PostgreSQL Manual: Pattern Matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-matching.html)